# Git p4 merge pull request

Tags: git, github, merge, perforce, p4v

I have a project that is up on GitHub.  Locally I am using Perforce and git p4 to push commits to GitHub.  I recently merged a pull request but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to merge it from my git repo into my Perforce workspace.  Obviously I could just grab the files from the git repo and move them by hand into my workspace, truthfully this project is very small and that wouldn't be an issue, but if I'm working on a larger project I'd like to know how to do this better.

My git repo is good to go with the merge, but after trying git p4 sync, submit, and commit, nothing is moving files from the repo to my workspace.  git p4 rebase seems to only go from the workspace to the repo, not the other way around.

Does anyone know the proper workflow for this?

Answer (score 2):

You must rebase your GitHub repo to have a linear history
(using `git rebase`, not `git p4 rebase`) before you can copy the commits to your Perforce workspace.

From the [Git-p4 documentation](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/2790) (emphasis mine):

> Troubleshooting Merge Conflicts During Submission
>
> Git history might contain a merge. **Git-p4 cannot copy merge commits to Perforce. You must rebase or rewrite Git history to be linear before Git-p4 can copy it to Perforce.**

And a little further down on the page:

> Git-p4 cannot copy a branched or merged Git history to Perforce. When [a feature] is complete, they **add this feature to the master branch not by merging, but by recreating the branch commits on top of the the master branch**... For details, read about "git rebase".
>
> If branches cannot be rebased into a single linear history, delete them from history.